# Rows offset in appending data to CSV in Python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, append

I am using the following code to append an array of values

```
4.525223672389984131e-01
3.839516639709472656e-01
1.930356919765472412e-01
```

to an existing CSV file ("Testfile2.csv") which only contains 1 text field per row

```
Text A
Text B
Text C
```

using the following code:

```
csvfile = 'Testfile2.csv'
with open(csvfile, 'rb') as fin, open('new_'+csvfile, 'wb') as fout:
        indexation = 0
        for line in iter(fin.readline, ''):
            fout.write(line.replace('\n', ', ' + str(sims_mean[indexation]) + '\n'))
            indexation += 1
```

However, my output looks like this if opened in Excel

```
Text A
             4.525223672389984131e-01
Text B
             3.839516639709472656e-01
Text C
             1.930356919765472412e-01
```

Hence there are two issues:

- The appended values from the array are offset by 1 row compared to each entry.
- Between every line there is an unnecessary space.

How can I fix those two things?

Comment: My guess is you don't need an ' ' after comma and your text should be between "s like "Text A"

Comment: Consider using the `csv` package